# Proof Verification: Properties of Divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

**The Problem:**
Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that if $b \mid a$ and $b \nmid (a + c)$, then $b \nmid c$.

**My Answer So Far:**

By definition, we have $ a = bq_1$ and $\nexists q_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a+c= bq_2$ for $ q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Substituting $a = bq_1$ gives  $\nexists q_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $bq_1 + c = bq_2$ or $\nexists q_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $c = bq_2-bq_1$. By factoring out $b$ we have $\nexists q_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $c = b(q_2-q_1)$. Substituting $q_3=q_2-q_1$. we have $\nexists q_3 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $c = bq_3$.

$\therefore \; b \nmid c$ if $b \mid a$ and $ b \nmid (a+c)$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$.

**My Question:**

How does my proof look? I now know that it is easier to prove the contrapositive, but is this proof just as valid?

Comment: Did you mean $a+\color{red}c\ne bq_2$?  It might be easier to show that, if $b|a$ and $b|c$, then $b|a+c$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yeah, I'll fix that. Also, this is based on a specific exercise in my abstract algebra book, so I know for a fact that this is the right question.

Comment: If you could show, given $b|a$, that $b|c\implies b|a+c$, then you have $b\nmid a+c\implies b\nmid c$ by contrapositive

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, thanks! I can't believe I didn't think of this but is my proof a valid one?

Comment: I think by $a+c\ne bq_2$ you mean $\not\exists q_2\in \mathbb Z$ such that $a+c=bq_2$

Comment: You're exactly right, I'm still learning when I need to use quantifiers. Can you explain the difference between these two statements?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104800/discussion-between-mark-s-and-j-w-tanner).

Comment: This statement is same as if $b\mid a$ and $b\mid c$ then $b\mid(a+c)$

Comment: Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926901/divisibility-if-a-mid-b-and-b-mid-c-then-a-mid-bc) post

Comment: @Manx I've proved this already, but I want to know if there's a way of proving this without having to prove this.