# Should I use an existential quantifier here?

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

In my question [Proof Verification: Properties of Divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3556788/proof-verification-properties-of-divisors?noredirect=1#comment7314069_3556788), I had originally said something along the lines of the following:

> Since $b \nmid (a+c)$ we have, by definition, $a+c \neq bq_2 \text{ for } q_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

But was told that I might have meant the following:

> Since $b \nmid (a+c)$ we have, by definition, $ \nexists q_2\in \mathbb{Z} \text{ such that }  a+c = bq_2$.

Is one of the previous more valid than the other and if so, why is it more appropriate to use? (i.e. Is there a difference between these two statements?)

Comment: Logically, $\forall q_2 \not P(q_2)$ is equivalent to $\not\exists q_2 P(q_2)$; the negation of a propositional function's [existential quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification#Negation) is a universal quantification of that propositional function's negation

Comment: Actually, your sentence 'for $q_2\in\Bbb Z$' hides an implicit quantifier but it's not clear which one you mean. You want 'for *all* $q_2\in\Bbb Z$'.

Comment: As per previous comments, there is an *implicit* quantifier, but which must be obvious. Start from definition: $b | (a+c) \text { iff  there is some } q_2 \in \mathbb Z \text { such that } a+c=bq_2$. Now, we have only to negate the definition..

Comment: We have : $\lnot (b | (a+c)) \text { iff } \lnot \exists q_2 \in \mathbb Z ((a+c)=bq_2)$ i.e. $\forall q_2 \in \mathbb Z ((a+c) \ne bq_2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first claim was not correct.

To correct it, you should indicate that the statement is universally true; like so:

> Since $b \nmid (a+c)$ we have, by definition, $a+c \neq bq_2 \text{ for }\textbf{any } q_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$$b\nmid(a+c)\iff \forall q_2\in\Bbb Z~.(a+c)\neq bq_2$$

Which is now equivalent to the second claim.

> Since $b \nmid (a+c)$ we have, by definition, $ \nexists q_2\in \mathbb{Z} \text{ such that }  a+c = bq_2$.

$$b\nmid(a+c)\iff \lnot\exists q_2\in\Bbb Z~.(a+c) = bq_2$$